# Slow performance on R (Spatial distance calculation)

Tags: r, optimization, gis, spatial

I am working with two shapefiles in R: one representing 5,841 localities (as points) and the other representing roads (as lines - total 99 observations). My objective is to calculate the minimum distance from each locality to the closest road and to identify the exact lat/lon location on the road that corresponds to this minimum distance. Essentially, for each point, I want to find the nearest point on any line and measure the distance between these two points.

Here is the approach I've taken, using the sf package:

```
library(sf)

# Load the shapefiles
localities <- st_read("path/to/localities.shp")
roads <- st_read("path/to/roads.shp")

# Ensure CRS match, transform if necessary
if (st_crs(localities) != st_crs(roads)) {
  roads <- st_transform(roads, st_crs(localities))
}

# Calculate nearest roads and distances
nearest_roads_info <- st_nearest_feature(localities, roads)
distances_to_nearest_road <- st_distance(localities, roads[nearest_roads_info, , drop = FALSE])
closest_points <- st_nearest_points(localities, roads[nearest_roads_info, , drop = FALSE])

# Extracting closest points on roads
closest_points_on_roads <- st_cast(closest_points, "POINT")[,2]

# Assigning distances and coordinates to the localities data frame
localities$distance_to_nearest_road <- distances_to_nearest_road
coords <- st_coordinates(st_sfc(closest_points_on_roads, crs = st_crs(localities)))
localities$closest_road_lat <- coords[, "Y"]
localities$closest_road_lon <- coords[, "X"]
```

The issue is this code takes forever to run. I suspect the slow performance might be due to the way I'm calculating distances and extracting the closest road points, but I'm not sure how best to optimize these operations. Any advice, tips, or alternative approaches I could follow?

Answer (score 1):

Two main things were slowing your down: `st_distance()` was creating a distance matrix of *all* distance relationships instead of just the pairs you wanted; and `st_nearest_points()` was calculating nearest points to *every* road instead of just the nearest road. Based on the sample data used in the solution below, with 5,841 localities, and 91 roads representing ~29km in total, this works in ~30 seconds. The workflow:

0. Create sample data. Obviously skip this if using your own data, but note the sample data column names and modify subsequent code to match your column names if necessary. The sample data are all in WGS84 (EPSG:4326).
1. Add `st_nearest_feature(roads)` to localities sf
2. Create empty sf (result) to hold results. Ensure the CRS values for result match your data (see code comment)
3. Loop through localities and roads by road_name, get `st_nearest_points()`, calculate `st_distance()`, and add results to result

**Sample data and required packages** (will throw warnings which can be safely ignored):

```
library(sf)
library(lwgeom) # For st_endpoint() (and st_split(), only for sample road sf)
library(dplyr) # For data wrangling/pipes e.g. %>%

set.seed(1) # For reproducibility

# Create example roads sf
tmp <- data.frame(localities_id = 1:30,
                  latitude = runif(30, min = 42.01, max = 42.04),
                  longitude = runif(30, min = 18.01, max = 18.03)) %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("longitude", "latitude"), crs = 4326) 

tmp <- tmp %>%
  st_union() %>% 
  st_voronoi() %>%
  st_collection_extract() %>%
  st_as_sf() %>%
  st_crop(., tmp) %>%
  st_cast(., "LINESTRING")

# Warning message:
#   In st_voronoi.sfc(.) :
#   st_voronoi does not correctly triangulate longitude/latitude data

roads <- st_cast(tmp, "POINT") %>%
  st_intersection() %>%
  st_split(tmp, .) %>%
  st_collection_extract(., "LINESTRING") %>%
  st_difference() %>%
  mutate(road_name = 1:n())

# although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_intersection assumes that they are planar
# although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_difference assumes that they are planar

# Create example localities sf
pt_cnt <- 5841

localities <- data.frame(localities_id = 1:pt_cnt,
                         latitude = runif(pt_cnt, min = 42, max = 42.05),
                         longitude = runif(pt_cnt, min = 18, max = 18.05)) %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("longitude", "latitude"), crs = 4326)
```

**Data prep and loop:**

```
# Add nearest road_name to localities (to use as for loop iteration value)
localities <- localities %>% mutate(road_name = st_nearest_feature(., roads))

# Create empty sf to hold loop results, edit CRS values for geometry and 
# road_point columns if necessary
result <- st_sf(localities_id = as.integer(1), 
                 road_name = as.integer(1),
                 distance_m = units::set_units(NA, m),
                 geometry = st_sfc(st_geometrycollection(), crs = 4326),
                 road_point = st_sfc(st_geometrycollection(), crs = 4326)) %>%
  filter(!localities_id == 1) %>%
  st_set_crs(4326)

# Iterate over localities and roads based on road_name (i), find nearest road point,
# calculate distance, and output to result sf
for(i in unique(localities$road_name)) { #unique(localities$road_name)
  
  # st <- Sys.time()
  tmp1 <- filter(localities, road_name == i)
  tmp2 <- filter(roads, road_name == i)
  
  tmp3 <- tmp1 %>%
    mutate(road_point = st_endpoint(st_nearest_points(., tmp2)),
           distance_m = st_distance(geometry, road_point, by_element = TRUE))
  
  result <- bind_rows(result, tmp3) 
  # Sys.time() - st
  # print(paste("nearest to road", i, "took", round(Sys.time() - st, 2), "secs")) 
  
}

result
Simple feature collection with 5841 features and 3 fields
Active geometry column: geometry
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 18.00001 ymin: 42.00001 xmax: 18.04995 ymax: 42.05
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
First 10 features:
   localities_id road_name     distance_m                  geometry                road_point
1              1        31  654.52899 [m] POINT (18.01805 42.04564) POINT (18.01805 42.03976)
2             16        31  539.56768 [m] POINT (18.01719 42.04461) POINT (18.01719 42.03976)
3             36        31   12.00564 [m] POINT (18.02073 42.03987) POINT (18.02073 42.03976)
4             44        31 1098.24481 [m] POINT (18.02109 42.04963) POINT (18.02109 42.03976)
5             61        31 1093.54231 [m] POINT (18.01973 42.04959) POINT (18.01973 42.03976)
6             90        31  385.82320 [m]  POINT (18.0213 42.04323)  POINT (18.0213 42.03976)
7            113        31  339.04799 [m] POINT (18.01616 42.04281) POINT (18.01616 42.03976)
8            265        31  333.21679 [m] POINT (18.02243 42.04275) POINT (18.02243 42.03976)
9            306        31  231.19469 [m] POINT (18.02239 42.04184) POINT (18.02239 42.03976)
10           328        31  203.05577 [m] POINT (18.01653 42.04158) POINT (18.01653 42.03976)
```

Here's a map of the results with a subset of localities to illustrate that it works:
[image: result]